# Strange behaviour of the Thunderbird mail sending window

Tags: email, thunderbird

When I open the mail sending window in Thunderbird (Ubuntu 21.10), send the mail, and close the sending window the dot next to the Thunderbird icon is not deleted. So there are two dots but only one Thunderbird window. When I close Thunderbird after this the dot next to the icon remains and I'm unable to launch Thunderbird again by clicking the icon. Is this bug going to be corrected?

Comment: bugs should be reported on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect

Comment: Done, bug #1951823.